# Log in with txt file

Tags: python, authentication, text

Hi i cant get this to work. Can anyone help? No matter what you input, it seems to validate the input as true, which it obviously shouldn't.

```
filename = "db.txt"

def login():
    print("LOGIN PAGE")
    input_username = input(str("Enter your username :"))
    input_password = input(str("Enter your password :"))
    logged_in = False
    with open('db.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            username, password = line.split(',')
            if username == input_username:
                logged_in = password == input_password
                break

    if logged_in:
        print("LOGGED IN")

    else:
        signup()


# Register user

def signup():
    print("SIGN UP PAGE")
    file = open("db.txt", "a")
    regusername = input("Enter a username :")
    regpassword = input("Enter a password :")
    file.write(regusername + ":" + regpassword)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    login()

login_or_signup = input("Do you want to log in or sign up :")

if login_or_signup == "log in":
    login()

elif login_or_signup == "sign up":
    signup()

else:
    print("Failed")
```

Comment: Why do you store passwords `:`-seperated and split them them `,`-seperated?

Comment: input takes a string to print, `str("Enter your username :")` why put a string inside `str(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in my comment yesterday: you need to split your data by the same token you write into the file:

Write:

> ```
> file.write(regusername + ":" + regpassword)   
> file.write("\n")
> ```

Read:

> ```
> username, password = line.split(',')           # use : instead of ,
> ```

Beside that - you add a `'\n'` after the PW so if you read your file with

> ```
> with open('db.txt', 'r') as file:
>     for line in file:
>         username, password = line.split(',')
> ```

your password will include this `'\n'` - you need to remove it if you compare it against the password gotten by `input_password = input("Enter your password :")` which has NO `'\n'` at its end:

```
 with open('db.txt', 'r') as file:
     for line in file:
         username, password = line.strip().split(',')
```

When you are at it, remove the unneeded `str()` around strings and change your file handling inside `def signup()` to use `with open (...) as file: ...` as well.

Answer (score -2):

There were 3 errors that I could see.

1. You were doing check for `input_password` wrong.
2. Setting `logged_in` to `True` was not done properly.
3. You are writing the `username and password` into file with separator `':'` and trying to split using `','`.

Try this :

```
filename = "db.txt"

def login():
    print("LOGIN PAGE")
    input_username = input("Enter your username :")
    input_password = input("Enter your password :")
    logged_in = False
    with open('db.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            username, password = line.split(',')
            if username == input_username and password == input_password:
                logged_in = True
                break

    if logged_in:
        print("LOGGED IN")

    else:
        signup()


# Register user

def signup():
    print("SIGN UP PAGE")
    file = open("db.txt", "a")
    regusername = input("Enter a username :")
    regpassword = input("Enter a password :")
    file.write(regusername + "," + regpassword)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    login()

login_or_signup = input("Do you want to log in or sign up :")

if login_or_signup == "log in":
    login()

elif login_or_signup == "sign up":
    signup()

else:
    print("Failed")
```

Comment: When i try to put the right login in the input it still does not work

Comment: What is happening ? Can you elaborate, maybe I could help.

Comment: It puts me to the sign up page even with the right login

Comment: The txt file login is a,a

Comment: It stil outputs this

Comment: Do you see any space in username, password entered ? Try printing username and password when you fetch it from the file.

Comment: Do you want to log in or sign up :log in
LOGIN PAGE
Enter your username :a
Enter your password :a
SIGN UP PAGE
Enter a username :

Comment: Great. Where was the problem ?

Comment: @PrashantKumar, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, it say that the person asking is not to be pressured into accepting.

Comment: I did not pressurize anyone to accept. It was a request and since user is new he might not be knowing about this so I asked.